# How to assert a response from callout when the webservice callout happened in a controller method? Experts advice please

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller

I have built a visualforce page, a controller. The methods in controller contains the logic to make a webservice callout and assigning the response to class variables.

Static utility methods have been written separately in an Apex class to build the webservice request to the webservice and parse the callout response.

Now, I need to validate the callout response using System.assertequals statement. Please suggest. Thanks

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class CCInfoController {
    private final Account acct;
    public CustomerCreditInfo cci {get; private set;} 
    public String CustNo {get;set;}
    private List<String> lstReqData {get;set;}
    public Boolean displayCustomerCreditInfo {get; set;}

    public CCInfoController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
            List<String> addl = new List<String> {};
            addl.add('accountnumber');
            stdController.addFields(addl);
        }
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
        System.debug('acct:'+acct);
        if(CustNo == null) {
            CustNo = acct.AccountNumber; //'1172';
            //CustNo = '1172';
        }
    }

    public Pagereference ViewCustomerCreditInfo() {
        displayCustomerCreditInfo = true;
        cci = FetchCustomerCreditInfo();
        return null;
    }

    public CustomerCreditInfo FetchCustomerCreditInfo() {
        try {
            DMsapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00_Binding sap1;
            gsswdNetWebservice.webServices_Provider_finalProvider_esyConnectorGenricServiceProviderNew_Port sap2;

            DMsapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response_element ret1;
            gsswdNetWebservice.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00Response ret2;

            Map<String,String> mapSAP = new Map<String,String> {};
                lstReqData = new List<String> {};

            //populating item values
            String EventType = 'EVENT[.]SFDC-CUSTOMER-CREDIT-INFO-GET[.]VERSION[.]0[.]RESPONSE-TYPE[.]FULL-SETS';
            String InputFields = '';
            String InputData = 'ZGSEST_CSTMRSRCH01[.]'+CustNo;
            lstReqData.add(EventType);
            lstReqData.add(InputFields);
            lstReqData.add(InputData);
            system.debug('Utility.getMiddleWare():::'+Utility.getMiddleWare());

            sap1 = new DMsapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.Z_GSSMWFM_HNDL_EVNTRQST00_Binding();       
            sap1.timeout_x = 120000;
            ProcessorControl.inGetCreditInfo = true;  
            DMsapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01 req = new DMsapComDocumentSapSoapFunctionsMcS.ZgssmbstDatarcrd01();      
            req.item = Utility.LoadRequestData(lstReqData); //utility method to build the request to webservice
            System.debug('request value:'+req);
            ret1 =  sap1.ZGssmwfmHndlEvntrqst00('',req);
            System.debug('Return value:'+ret1);
            mapSAP = Utility.ParseResponse(ret1); //Utility method to parse the response from webservice callout

            cci = new CustomerCreditInfo(); 
            System.debug('mapSAP values:'+mapSAP.keyset());
            if(!mapSAP.isEmpty() && mapSAP.size()>0) {
                cci.CreditBlock = mapSAP.get('CRBLB');
                cci.RiskCategory = mapSAP.get('CTLPC');
                cci.RiskClass = mapSAP.get('CTLPC_TEXT');
                cci.Rating = mapSAP.get('DBRTG');
            }  
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Customer Credit Info Exception:'+e.getStackTraceString());
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Oops, please try again!');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }
        return cci;
    }


//Wrapper for Customer Credit Info

    public class CustomerCreditInfo {
        public String CreditBlock{get; set;} //MONTH_1
        public String CountryKey{get; set;} //UMNETWR_CUR
        public String RiskCategory{get; set;} //UMNETWR
        public String Name1 {get;set;} //UMWAVWR_CUR
        public String RiskClass{get; set;} //UMWAVWR    
        public Decimal CreditExposure{get; set;} //UMKZWI1_CUR
        public String Rating{get;set;} //UMKZWI1
    }
}
```

**Visualforce:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="CustomerCreditInfoController" standardStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/zen-componentsCompatible.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/elements.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/rlHovers.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/chatterCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/chatterExtended.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/SocialCrm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/SocialKeyCRM.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1400172052000/Theme3/base/dStandard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/><link href="/sCSS/30.0/sprites/1401314678000/Theme3/default/base/extended.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <c:LoadingBox />
    <body>
        <!-- <c:PageLoadingAnimation /> -->
        <apex:pageMessages />       
        <apex:form id="cciForm">
            <div id="ccicontainer" style="float:left;width:75%">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!ViewCustomerCreditInfo}" value="Get SAP Data" id="btnCCI" status="loadStatus" rerender="cciForm"/>
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%">
                <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!displayCustomerCreditInfo}">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

                        <apex:outputText label="Credit Block" value="{!If(cci.creditblock=='','No','Yes') }" id="creditblock"/>          
                        <!-- <apex:outputText label="Risk Category" value="{!cci.RiskCategory}" id="riskcategory"/> -->
                        <apex:outputText label="Rating" value="{!cci.Rating}" id="rating"/>
                        <apex:outputText label="Risk Category" value="{!cci.RiskClass}" id="riskclass"/>

                        <apex:outputText label="Credit Limit" id="creditlimit" value="{0,number,currency}">  
                            <apex:param value="{!cci.CreditLimit}" />  
                        </apex:outputText>              

                        <apex:outputText label="Credit Limit Used" value="{!cci.CreditLimitUsed}" id="creditlimitused"/>
                        <!--<apex:outputText label="Country Key" value="{!cci.CountryKey}" id="countrykey"/>-->
                        <!--<apex:outputText label="Name" value="{!cci.name1}" id="name"/>-->

                        <apex:outputText label="Credit Exposure" id="creditexposure" value="{0,number,currency}">  
                            <apex:param value="{!cci.CreditExposure}" />  
                        </apex:outputText>              

                        <!--<apex:outputText label="City" value="{!cci.City}" id="city"/>-->
                        <!--<apex:outputText label="Region" value="{!cci.Region}" id="region"/> -->
                        <apex:outputText label="Currency Key" value="{!cci.CurrencyKey}" id="currencykey"/>

                    </apex:pageBlockSection>

                </apex:pageBlock>
            </div>
        </apex:form>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)

public with sharing class testCCInfoController  {
    public static testMethod void testCustomerCreditInfo() {
        Account a = new Account(Name='Tester', 
        AccountNumber='101552',
        Rating = 'Hot',
        NumberOfEmployees = 10,
        Description = 'test'
        );
        insert a;
        MiddleWare__c mw = [SELECT id FROM MiddleWare__c WHERE name = 'esyconnector'];
        mw.Active__c = true;
        update mw;

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
        CCInfoController CC = new CCInfoController(sc); 
        CC.ViewCustomerCreditInfo();     

        //********How to assert the response here? *********
        Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are parsing the response from the webservice into a custom wrapper class object ,you can verify that the custom wrapper object has proper value populated

```
Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImpl());

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
    CCInfoController CC = new CCInfoController(sc); 
    CC.ViewCustomerCreditInfo();     

    //********How to assert the response here? *********
    system.assert(CC.cci.CreditBlock,'your mock value');//Note your mock value is the sample response data provided in your mock class
    system.assert(CC.cci.CountryKey,'your mock value');
    system.assert(CC.cci.RiskCategory,'your mock value');
    system.assert(CC.cci.Name1 ,'your mock value');
    Test.stopTest();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohith. Is that enough to assert only the webservice response in a callout related apex classes? Or do we need to assert anything else, for example, to check if the Account is created or not? Usually what are other things we need to assert in an apex class either with a callout or without a callout? I know its a broad question, but any hint from you would be helpful to follow. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: You should assert the logical points that are mentioned in business requirement .example if your class suppose to create Account assert that new Account was formed .If your method is redirected to a different page assert the redirection lands in proper navigation path .For your case assert values that came from mock webservice

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mohith. Would try to implement your valid inputs.